# ORACLE APEX USING LOV ON SELECT STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Hey I am new on sql\apex
I try to make a select stetment based on page item!!
I want in the first loading to show me all
and then after selectd item from the list it show me only the the related value

this is my code :

```
select ID,
       MAKE,
       TYPE,
       YEAR,
       MODEL,
       APEX$SYNC_STEP_STATIC_ID,
       APEX$ROW_SYNC_TIMESTAMP
  from API_CARS
where MAKE = :P2_FILTER
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify `WHERE` clause to

```
where make = :P2_FILTER or :P2_FILTER is null
      -----------------    ------------------
      this will return        this will return 
      only values related     all rows in the table
      to a LoV item           (at the beginning, when         
                              LoV hasn't been used yet)
```